# How to create swipe button left and right?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

How to create swipe button left and right ?

i have try create Swipe button to confirmation (swipe left to right)

my code:

```
class SwipeOnOffButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String timer;
  final double timerSize;
  final TextStyle timerStyle;
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color disableBackgroundColor;
  final Color replaceBackgroundColor;
  final Color foregroundColor;
  final Color iconColor;
  final IconData leftIcon;
  final IconData rightIcon;
  final double iconSize;
  final String text;
  final TextStyle textStyle;
  final VoidCallback onConfirmation;
  final BorderRadius foregroundRadius;
  final BorderRadius backgroundRadius;
  final bool disable;

  const SwipeOnOffButton({
    Key key,
    this.timer,
    this.timerSize,
    this.timerStyle,
    this.height = 48.0,
    this.width = 300,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.disableBackgroundColor,
    this.foregroundColor,
    this.iconColor,
    this.leftIcon,
    this.text,
    this.textStyle,
    @required this.onConfirmation,
    this.foregroundRadius,
    this.backgroundRadius,
    this.rightIcon,
    this.iconSize,
    this.replaceBackgroundColor,
    this.disable = false,
  });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SwipeOnOffButtonState();
  }
}

class SwipeOnOffButtonState extends State<SwipeOnOffButton> {
  double _position = 0;
  int _duration = 0;
  bool _isSwipe = false;

  double getPosition() {
    if (widget.disable) _position = 0;
    if (_position < 0) {
      return 0;
    } else if (_position > widget.width - widget.height) {
      return widget.width - widget.height;
    } else {
      return _position;
    }
  }

  Color getColor() {
    if (!widget.disable) {
      if (_position > 0) {
        return widget.replaceBackgroundColor ?? Colors.green;
      } else {
        return widget.backgroundColor ?? Colors.orange;
      }
    } else {
      return widget.disableBackgroundColor ?? Colors.black;
    }
  }

  void updatePosition(details) {
    if (!widget.disable) {
      if (details is DragEndDetails) {
        setState(() {
          _duration = 100;
          _position = _isSwipe ? widget.width : 0;
        });
      } else if (details is DragUpdateDetails) {
        setState(() {
          _duration = 0;
          _position = _isSwipe
              ? _position
              : details.localPosition.dx - (widget.height / 2);
        });
      }
    } else {
      _position = 0;
    }
  }

  void swipeReleased(details) {
    if (_position > widget.width - widget.height) {
      widget.onConfirmation();
      _isSwipe = true;
    }
    updatePosition(details);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: widget.height,
      width: widget.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: widget.backgroundRadius ??
            BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(widget.height)),
        color: !widget.disable
            ? widget.backgroundColor ?? Colors.orange
            : Colors.black,
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedContainer(
            height: widget.height,
            width: getPosition() + widget.height,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: _duration),
            curve: Curves.bounceOut,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: widget.backgroundRadius ??
                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(widget.height)),
                color: getColor()),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text(
              widget.text ?? "Start",
              style: widget.textStyle ??
                  ThemeData.textTheme.buttonText1
                      .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: _duration),
            curve: Curves.bounceOut,
            left: getPosition(),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onPanUpdate: (details) => updatePosition(details),
              onPanEnd: (details) => swipeReleased(details),
              child: !_isSwipe
                  ? Container(
                      height: widget.height,
                      width: widget.height,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: widget.foregroundRadius ??
                            BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(widget.height / 2),
                            ),
                        color: widget.foregroundColor ??
                            Colors.white.withOpacity(0.24),
                      ),
                      child: Icon(
                        widget.leftIcon ?? Icons.arrow_circle_up_rounded,
                        color: widget.iconColor ?? Colors.white,
                        size: widget.iconSize ?? 20.0,
                      ),
                    )
                  : Container(
                      height: widget.height,
                      width: widget.height,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: widget.foregroundRadius ??
                            BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(widget.height / 2),
                            ),
                        color: widget.foregroundColor ??
                            Colors.white.withOpacity(0.24),
                      ),
                      child: Icon(
                        widget.rightIcon ?? Icons.check_circle_rounded,
                        color: widget.iconColor ?? Colors.white,
                        size: widget.iconSize ?? 20.0,
                      ),
                    ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: swipe to confirm]

but i need swipe button have value bool (swipe to right=true and swipe to left=false)

so, i try to improve my swipe button. but, i can't find solution

could you help me to fix this problem?

Comment: use `AnimationController`, something like this:  https://gist.github.com/pskink/9473bff3b37d171332a0aeaedfef5bd8

Comment: sorry, i don't understand.. can you explain it ? @pskink

Comment: i see vertical swipe... i can't find how to change to horizontal.. i try change alignment begin: Alignment.centerLeft, end: Alignment.centerRight. Ball get horizontal swipe. but, gesture still vertical @pskink

Comment: *"but, gesture still vertical"* - you need `onHorizontalDragUpdate: dragUpdate,
onHorizontalDragEnd: dragEnd`, not `onVerticalDrag*`

Answer (score -1):

Use [lite_rolling_switch](https://pub.dev/packages/lite_rolling_switch) package

```
LiteRollingSwitch(
                value: true,
                textOn: 'active',
                textOff: 'inactive',
                colorOn: Colors.deepOrange,
                colorOff: Colors.blueGrey,
                iconOn: Icons.lightbulb_outline,
                iconOff: Icons.power_settings_new,
                onChanged: (bool state) {
                  print('turned ${(state) ? 'on' : 'off'}');
                },
              ),
```

Comment: is not swipe button